# Can you print 2 Excel sheets side by side in the same page

Tags: excel, vba, printing

The Print Layout Pages per Sheet allows you to set the value, but the number of sheets then prints vertically

```
    Sheet1
    Sheet2
```

I need them to print side by side instead with each sheet taking up 50%

```
    S    S
    h    h
    e    e
    e    e
    t    t
    1    2
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Not sure if this can be achieved in Excel itself, but check your printer properties. I got one that allows me to print *2 pages per side*, but it's an option of the printer itself.

Comment: You could certainly write some VBA code which would create new sheet, copy the data and formatting from both sheets into this one new sheet and print out that one. Or do it manually but if you'll need to do this a lot, VBA should do the trick.

Comment: There are applications able to do it (Corel, for instance, for any custom dimensions - through VBA, too), but I am afraid that **this cannot be done in/from Excel**. But you can obtain the above shown way preliminarily processing a little the two sheets in discussion... I mean to copy the second one content. Is the example you show relevant? I mean, only one column for each? Anyhow, even if allowing to print side by side, Excel would print two full pages, meaning that the second sheet would be placed far away from the first column of the first one, if not all the page width will be filled...

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next workaround. It joins the two sheets side by side in a temporary workbook, appropriately set `PageSetup`, `PrintOut` then, close the temporary `wbP`:

```
Sub TwoSheetsPerPage()
   Dim wb As Workbook, sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, wbP As Workbook, lastCol As Long
   
   Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
   Set sh1 = wb.Worksheets(1)
   Set sh2 = wb.Worksheets(2)
   
   sh1.Copy 'this creates a new workbook with only the content of the first sheet
   
   Set wbP = ActiveWorkbook
   Set sh1 = wbP.Sheets(1)
   lastCol = sh1.cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).column
   
   'join the two sheets content, side by side
   With sh2.UsedRange
        sh1.cells(1, lastCol + 1).Resize(.rows.count, .Columns.count).Value = .Value
   End With
   
   
   'setting the PageSetup to accept all  columns:
   With sh1.PageSetup
        .PrintArea = sh1.UsedRange.address
        .FitToPagesWide = 1
   End With
   
   'print the newly created workbook
    sh1.PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False
    
    wbP.Close False 'close the temporary workbook
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be to create a third sheet, copy the range from Sheet1 you want and paste it as Linked Picture (in the Paste dropdown, Other Paste Options, to the right) on Sheet3, resize to fit, and then do the same with Sheet2:

[image]

The advantage is that it updates when changes happen on sheet1 and 2 and you can add other text and formatting, the downside is that it increases the size of the workbook, and if you have a complex workbook, it might increase the risk of problems.